# How to multiple iterate and show data under dynamically created table?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to create a dynamic table in ajax jquery and place value.
I wrote the code as follows:

```
function salesList() {
$("#data-title").html("");
$("#data-table").html('');
$.ajax({
    url: location.href + 'sales',
    method: "post",
    success: function (response) {
        let data_keys = [];
        data_keys = Object.keys(response.data[0]);
        $data_length = response.data.length;
        console.log($data_length);
        $("#data-title").html("This is Sale List");
        $("#data-table").append("<thead><tr></tr></thead>");
        $.each(data_keys, function (key, value) {
            $("#data-table>thead>tr").append("<td>" + value + "</td>")
        });
        $("#data-table").append("<tbody></tbody>");
        $.each(response.data, function (key, value) {
            $("#data-table>tbody").append("<tr>" + $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                $("#data-table>tbody>tr").append("<td>" + value + "</td>")
            }) + "</tr>");
        });

    }
});
```

}

But problem is table shown as follows.
[image]

means that every row in inserting under a row where I'm trying to insert only one row under a table row and second data row under second table row . How to write the code to do so? thank you.

I want the output to be like

[image]

I want each row of my output to be only under table head column. but here output is over printing outside actual column. I don't want this. there is some problem in my code. pls correct it.

Comment: Please try to clarify your issue a bit more. Preferably, provide a sample of the desired output.

Comment: How can I upload the desired output image in comment section as it seems not to be possible.

Comment: Please edit your question to add any additional info you need to add.

Comment: I want  each row of my output to be only under table head column. but here output is over printing outside actual column. I don't want this. there is some problem in my code. pls correct it.

Comment: I updated my desired output. Pls solve it now.